# How can I dynamically change the Notification message when I aggregate multiple notifications in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, android-c2dm

I'm trying to perform this simple task dealing with push notifications in Android (C2DM):

- if no notification exists in the notification bar, set it to "foo A"
- if a notification already exists, grab it, read its text, and then update it to something like "N notifications: foo, bar, ...". This is similar to what the gmail client would do on Android when you get 1 email vs multiple ones

I have looked through the docs, read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating, searched SO and the web, but so far, I don't see a way to get access to the notification currently in the notification bar.

Do I need to manage the count elsewhere and have it reset when the user dismisses the notification? Is there no way to read the existing one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if a notification already exists, grab it, read its text, and then update it to something like "N notifications: foo, bar, ...". This is similar to what the gmail client would do on Android when you get 1 email vs multiple ones

No, it isn't. Gmail already has this information in a database. It does not need to "grab [a notification], read its text".

Moreover, what you want is impossible.

> Do I need to manage the count elsewhere and have it reset when the user dismisses the notification?

Yes.

> Is there no way to read the existing one?

No.